# Access controller's function in the app.run

Tags: angularjs, facebook

Is it possible to call a function from child controller in `app.run`?

my sub-app facebook controller:

```
function faceBookController ($scope, $rootScope, faceBookService) {

    // I want to call this #scope.init in  app.run

    $scope.init =  function () {
        checkLoginState();
    };

    function checkLoginState () {
         faceBookService.init();
    }
}

angular.module('app.facebook').controller('faceBookController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'faceBookService', faceBookController]);
```

app.run:

```
function runFunction (User, $rootScope) {

*****

$window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '************',
        version    : 'v2.5' // use graph api version 2.5
    });

    //Here after facebook sdk connected execute init fruntion from faceBookController.

    $rootScope.init();
}

angular.module('app.run', []).run(['User', '$rootScope', runFunction]);
```

and main app.js file:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'app.run', 'app.facebook']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your run you can call the controller function like below
You can give an id for the div where the scope of the controller belongs,

```
<div id="yourcontainer" ng-app="test" ng-controller="faceBookController">
</div>
```

and then,

```
function runFunction (User, $rootScope) {
$window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '************',
        version    : 'v2.5' // use graph api version 2.5
    });
   var scope = ngular.element(document.getElementById('yourcontainer')).scope();
   scope.init();   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but do you think its correct approach? Or is there any other way to achieve the same result in its best? I mean would do the same if you were me and is that solution best approach?

Comment: @developer This is the way to access controller's function, since i have no idea on what you are trying to do , i can comment on the best approach

Comment: I'm authenticating user trough facebook, so I have got service called `faceBookService` that holds all the business logic - like first it check if user is logged in and then run the required request to the facebook api.. And there's a controller called `faceBookController` that `init`'s that service. But before all in app.run I have placed the code that connects to facebook to make requests. So the controller should call the method from  service after app.run has ran - after connection established with facebook.

Comment: i think you can purely handle this with the controller alone, rather than using app.run.

Comment: You mean by placing the whole thing in app.run https://jsfiddle.net/1p8u8xfb/1/ to Controller?

Comment: yeah sort of, let me know if it does not

Comment: But shouldn't the business logic be outside the controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153542/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-developer).